# How to format with a UNICODE string to JINJA's variable in a template?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

How to set format a string with unicode value in Jinja2 template?

```
{% set left='<span class="link" onclick="toggleLoginRegister(this)">{0}</span>'.format( registerHint ) %}
```

Raises UnicodeEncodeError if **registerHint** is a unicode string. Otherwise doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried appending and `u` before the string? `u'<span class="link" onclick="toggleLoginRegister(this)">{0}</span>'`

Comment: @PauloBu TemplateSyntaxError at /: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'string'

Comment: @PauloBu: Jinja2 expressions are not Python; they look a *lot* like Python but a dedicated parser is being used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I got it, it was just a hunch :) I was gonna suggest `decode` before I saw your answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`|format()` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#format) instead and Jinja will decode your string literal to `unicode` for you:

```
{% set left='<span class="link" onclick="toggleLoginRegister(this)">%s</span>'|format( registerHint ) %}
```